# Transform SQL query to Linq left join clause incorrect

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to select the MatchingObjects that doesn't exist in the Unlock table , I have this SQL query as following:

```
select a.* from MatchingObjects a 
    left join Unlocks b
        on a.ObjectCategoryId = b.ObjectCategoryId
    left join Members c
        on b.StudentId = c.Id
            and b.StudentId = @studentId
where  b.ObjectCategoryId is null
    and c.id is null
order by a.ObjectCategoryId
```

And a LINQ query

```
var query = (from d in db.ObjectCategories
                     join a in db.MatchingObjects on d.Id equals a.ObjectCategoryId into grp3
                     join b in db.Unlocks
                         on d.Id equals b.ObjectCategoryId into grp1
                     from m in grp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join c in db.Members
                         on m.StudentId equals c.Id into grp2
                     from n in grp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where m.ObjectCategoryId == null
                     && n.Id == null
                     orderby d.Id).AsEnumerable()
                     ;
```

However, the LINQ query is not showing the same result as that I want like in the SQL query. Could you guys tell me what I should change in my LINQ Query?

This is the model:
[image]

Comment: for me it's not the same query!! you must start from the same table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys, the Sql and the LINQ query was a bit different in table selection. I'm sorry about that because I was trying different Linq while posting the question, but The main problem is at the join clause

```
(from d in db.ObjectCategories
                     join a in db.MatchingObjects
                        on d.Id equals a.ObjectCategoryId into grp3
                     join b in db.Unlocks
                        on d.Id equals b.ObjectCategoryId into grp1
                     from m in grp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join c in db.Members 
                        on m.StudentId equals studentId into grp2
                     from n in grp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where m.ObjectCategoryId == null
                     where n.Id == null
                     orderby d.Id).AsEnumerable()


/* this is the correct one */
join c in db.Members 
on m.StudentId equals studentId into grp2

/* the below was the original incorrect join clause*/
join c in db.Members
on m.StudentId equals c.Id into grp2
```

Answer (score 1):

Better you can use below tools:

An SQL-> LINQ converter..

1. **http://www.sqltolinq.com**
2. **http://www.linqpad.net/**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Vignesh Kumar, I'll try it later to see if it match my expected result, however my pc at the workplace could not install the external softwares

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var query = from m in db.MatchingObjects.Where(w => w.ObjectCategoryId == null)
                            join u in db.Unlocks.Where(w => w.studentId == @studentId)
                                on m.ObjectCategoryId equals u.ObjectCategoryId into joinedU
                            from ju in joinedU.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join m in db.Members.Where(w => w.id == null)
                                on ju.StudentId equals m.Id into joinedM
                            from jm in joinedM.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select m;
```

But your request is a bit Strange. You make the join by ObjectCategoryId and in the Where clause you put ObjectCategoryId  == null!!!

Comment: Hi, Amine , thanks for your reply, but I'm sorry this is incorrect

Comment: == null is necessary for the left join